# Why does Outlook play a sound upon new mail while this is disabled?

Tags: audio, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I have disabled new sound on new email arrival in my Outlook 2013 a long time ago and it worked fine.
Out of a sudden Outlook is making a sound again, even though it is disabled:

[image]

This happened without any new software installed, without new Windows Updates.
Any idea where this may come form (and how to fix it)?

Comment: Just a wild guess: do you have any matching rules which might play a sound?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: thanks for the suggestion, but no. I have this setting disabled for years (I am never interested to know that an email comes in - thus the "all disabled" settings) and out of a sudden it started to work today.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 8/8.1 it comes from **Notifications**. You can open this new chime by moving mouse to the bottom right corner of the screen, click **Settings** -> **Change PC settings** (bottom of the chime). There you can find the **Notifications** tab. You can turn the notifications on/off. To change the actual sound you can use good old **Control Panel**'s **Sound** applet.

Answer (score 1):

For me, after disabling everything above - and almost throwing the computer out the window, I found that it was under App Volume and Device Preferences - and the App triggering the sound was Microsoft Edge.  When I turned down that volume, the horrible chime stopped.

Answer (score 1):

If you use both Outlook and OWA, as I do, then you will need to switch sounds off in each of them separately.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is not a proper solution but I did not have enough reputation to comment.

I had this same problem with my Outlook 2013 on a Windows 7 system. About a week ago, Outlook started playing a short musical sound for all incoming emails. I had already disabled sounds everywhere I could think of:

- in `"File"-tab > Options > Mail > Message arrival`
- in "Manage Rules & Alerts" (under `"Home"-tab > Rules`)
- in the "Sound" applet in Control Panel
- in outlook.office365.com

In an attempt to determine what caused this sound I then enabled a sound for the `New Mail Notification` event in the Control Panel Sound applet. I chose one that would sound weird enough so that I would recognize it as being my choice.

The odd thing is that after doing this I no longer got sound notifications for incoming emails. The sounds were gone even after I later changed that `New Mail Notification` event sound back to "(None)".

So fiddling with the event sounds (inadvertently) solved this problem in my case.

Answer (score -1):

For me on Windows 10, it were the `Settings -> System -> Notifications & actions -> Get notifications from these senders -> Outlook`. There the whole `Notifications` could be disabled, or just `Play a sound when a notification arrives`.